# Runtime attempts to look for exe/dll instead of the .winmd reference

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, clr, winmd

I have an app that uses a referenced library.
That library in turn references a .winmd library.

Looking at the referenced library's IL, i can seee this reference:

```
.assembly extern windowsruntime FlurryWin8SDK
{
  .ver 0:9:0:0
}
```

At runtime however, i am getting an exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'FlurryWin8SDK' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"FlurryWin8SDK"}
```

Also, by using Procmon i see that there are attempts searching for FlurryWin8SDK.exe and FlurryWin8SDK.dll, but not for a file with .winmd extension.

Also, this is the output from Fusion logviewer:

```
BEGIN : Framework bind.
END   : The provided identity format is not recognized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80132003)
BEGIN : Windows Runtime Type bind.
END   : The provided identity format is not recognized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80132003)
BEGIN : Immersive bind.
END   : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

What could be the reason for this odd behaviour ?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have very similar problem in WP 8.1 with my own WinMD component.

Answer (score 2):

It is not odd behavior.  WinRT put a hard stop to DLL Hell, the kind of problem you cannot expect a store user to troubleshoot.  A very hard requirement is that all dependencies are included with the app package.  And Windows will only look in that package for the DLL.

This makes uses a .winmd file a bit less than useful.  You'd only consider it in a large product that's built from many separate solutions that get packaged separately.

Comment: A .winmd file doesn't contain any code, just declarations.  Your program falls over when it tries to find the code.

Comment: Flurry put their code in the .winmd file... I can see the actual code in Reflector.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anybody named "Flurry", sounds like a pet name :)  No, a .winmd file only contains declarations.  Easy to get it confused with a .NET assembly, the .winmd file format is identical to the .NET metadata format and can be viewed with a .NET disassembler.  Maybe Flurry renamed such a .NET assembly, I really don't know.  The error message certainly ought to be good evidence that it works like this.

Comment: I meant www.flurry.com and by creating your own winmd components, it is possible to have both code and metadata in a winmd file. I believe this is the behavior in this case, as this is the only explanation since when i rename the winmd to dll, it loads fine and can be used correctly. Still this doesn't explain why the runime attempts to look for dll and not winmd...

Answer (score 2):

Managed WinRT types can sometimes have code embedded in the winmd file. However if the .net assembly contains any public types that aren't WinRT types, they will be in a .Net assembly with the .Dll extension. It's possible that your component contains code in the DLL as well as the winmd file.